# Change characters at specific position in a string in SAS

Tags: sas

IS there a function to change letters at a given index in SAS?

For example if my string is

`string1 = 'abcd1234efgh'`

I want to do somehing like:

`string2 = somefunction(string1, 5, 'zzzz');`

to produce

`'abcdzzzzefgh'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `substr() =` is what you're looking for. See [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212267.htm) for details.

```
substr(string2, 5) = 'zzzz';
```

The `substr(variable,position<,length>) =` function can also take an third argument to define the length of the segment to be replaced.

Comment: I would generally include the length in the substr argument, as best practice.

Comment: I wasn't even aware it could be omitted until I gabbed the user guide link just now, but it fits nicely with OP's prototype. I'll add a sentence to the answer for further clarity.

Comment: subpad() is a neat way to avoid warnings when the source variable is less than the length being substr'd..